# Angular 2 RC 4 Http post not firing

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to fire a post request for my app and it's not working, I tried multiple ways. I don't see the request being fired under the network tab in chrome. Not sure what the problem is, any help is appreciated.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class UserService{
   private _url="users";

   constructor(private _http: Http){
   }

   checkIfUsernameExists(username){
     return this._http.get(this._url+"/"+username)
               .map(response => response.json())
   }

   createUser(user){
     let headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
     console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    return this._http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify(user),{headers: headers})
                .map(response => response.json())
    }
```

}

Comment: From where  your `createUser` getting call ?

Comment: I missed to add subscribe in the component, after I added that it worked fine. surprised there is no error.

Comment: I think map was removed, it was used only in very old alpha versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need **capture** the **error** and solve the error:

```
this._http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify(user),{headers: headers})
      .subscribe(
      (res) => {
            // on success
      },
      (err) => {
            // on error
            console.error(err);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to call it like this so you can track the error

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type', 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

this.http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify(user),{headers: headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then( (res: Response) => {
          let body = res.json();
          this.authService.fillAuthDataFromLogin(body);
          this.router.navigate(['/Home']);
          return body.data || {};
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

**in this method handle the error**

```
  private handleError(error: any) {
    ////debugger;
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

call the service using promise

```
       this.UserService.createuser(user)
            .subscribe(
            data => { this.responseModel= data },
            error => console.log('error'),
            () => this.getComplete() //complete function
       );
```